# Internet Explorer Vuejs require polyfill Promise

Tags: internet-explorer, vue.js, promise, require, es6-promise

I really got no experience with Vuejs and now I have to fix a code for Internet Explorer. the First problem was, to fix all arrow Functions - nothing special, I did it.

The second one is I dont get any Content on the Website only in Internet Explorer - its working on Edge, Chrome etc....
 I really have no clue what to do i searched and tried everything, like npm installing require, babel-polyfill, promise, etc...

I hope someone can Help me here with Exact instruction what to do.
you can see the code on 
http://gebrauchtwagen.itpm.at/mvc2/index.html

Thank You

Comment: have a look at [this](https://github.com/stefanpenner/es6-promise)

Comment: The linked page doesn't load, please fix this.

Comment: the linked page load normally, there is no content to see.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll probably want to use [es6-promise](https://github.com/stefanpenner/es6-promise) - it works out-of-the-box with webpack (I'll assume that's what you're using because that's what most primers on Vue recommend).

All you need to do is install it with `npm` or `yarn` (instructions in the github repo), and then require it in your project:

```
import 'es6-promise/auto';
```

---

Later edit: saw you're just importing Vue from a CDN, so in your case, just import the Promise polyfill the same way:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/es6-promise@4/dist/es6-promise.auto.min.js"></script>
```

(instructions also in the repo)

Comment: I installed it and imported it but I get a syntaxerror like the last times I did this before. you can always see what i did on the link I sent before.

Comment: Try the second suggestion (using the `script` tag).

Comment: I did. Thanks, there is no error message anymore but still no Content. not only in IE

Comment: Helpful towards solving this for nuxt/vuejs: https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/480